# Click and Double click, deselect interaction OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

I have tow **ol.interaction.Select**, one to the single click and the other one to double click.

```
var selectDoubleClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
    multi: true,
    condition: ol.events.condition.doubleClick,
    style: function(feature) {
        //stuff here;
    }
    return feature;
}

selectDoubleClick.on('select',function(event) {
    //stuff here
}

var selectSingleClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
    multi: true,
    condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick,
    style: function(feature) {
        //stuff here
    }
    return feature;
}

selectSingleClick.on('select',function(event) {
    //stuff here
}
```

But when i want to deselect the double click, i have to click twice in the map. Is any way to deselect in double click with just one click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was simple. First very if exists any getFeature link to this interaction (selectDoubleClick), and then clear this features.

```
var concludeClickEdit = function(eventListener) {
    if(selectDoubleClick.getFeatures().getLength() !== 0){
             selectDoubleClick.getFeatures().clear();
          }
}
```